# Trigger to set field value

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm getting an error that a "Variable does not exist for Auto_Reneewal_Contract_End_Date" with this. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
trigger SetOverallContractEndDate on Contract_Terms__c (before insert, before update) {

  for (Contract_Terms ct : Trigger.new) {
          if (ct.Auto_Renewal_Contract_End_Date__c== "")
          ct.Overall_End_Date__c= ct.Contract_End_Date;
        else
          ct.Overall_End_Date__c = Auto_Renewal_Contract_End_Date__c;  
  }
}
```

Also, what's the best way to make the field I am populating non-editable ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the ct. prefix before Auto_Renewal_Contract_End_Date__c

```
 ct.Overall_End_Date__c = ct.Auto_Renewal_Contract_End_Date__c;
```

For making the field non-editable, well it depends on your specific requirements but the best way would be to set the profile permissions to remove the ability to edit that field. You may decide that some profiles should still be allowed to edit it.
You can also make it read-only on the page layout but this only affects interactions through that page, and not other means such as through the API (dataloader, excel connector etc.)
So - field level security in the profile would be the best way.

Comment: oh god - I didn't even notice that ! Thanks Doug !

btw - what's a good way to make that field un-editable to all users ? I just want to set it with the trigger all the time.

Thanks again.

Comment: Use field level security on the profiles to make the field read only. The Trigger executes in system context so it is still allowed to update the value.

Comment: @DougB Hi DougB , Is it possible to update a field which is read-only on page layout through trigger...

Comment: Yes, a trigger can update a field which is read-only on page layout.